# Salesforce custom objects accessing using selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

Each time SalesForce does a new release, most of the ID's of the elements on the salesforce webpage change(I use the ID property of the element to locate it with my automation code). This breaks my automation scripts.

In my case one text box named as "Question Name" i want to enter a value in this text box.

recent html:

```
<label class="label inputLabel uiLabel-left form-element__label uiLabel" for="7:1781;a" data-aura-rendered-by="1040:0" data-aura-class="uiLabel">
<span class="" data-aura-rendered-by="1041:0">Question Name</span>
<span class="required " data-aura-rendered-by="8:1781;a">*</span>
</label>
<input id="7:1781;a" class=" input" maxlength="80" aria-describedby="" placeholder="" required="" data-aura-rendered-by="11:1781;a" 
data-interactive-lib-uid="5" aria-required="true" type="text">
```

my existing xpath :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='6:2634;a']")).sendKeys("test");
```

Salesforce application all ID's are dynamically changed for every new release, my test script failed with the above xpath with Id, so please suggest me alternate solution.

how should i get the input id value in runtime? or let me know is there any other possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(., 'Question Name')]/following-sibling::input")).sendKeys("test");
```

This will search for a label containing the text 'Question Name' and then selects the following input sibling

Answer (score 1):

To enter a value in the text box named as **`"Question Name"`** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='label inputLabel uiLabel-left form-element__label uiLabel']/span[text()='Question Name']//following::input")).sendKeys("test");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help